# Reading daemon logs for wlan0

Tags: wireless, logs

I have a `Raspberry Pi` device which runs on `Raspbain Linux`. The device performs well on `wlan0` but from the last few days, it became offline (disconnected from the network). I thought of looking into some logs and found `daemon.log` file in `/var/log/` which contains some useful information about the network connectivity wlan0. I did `cat daemon.log | grep wlan0` and it showed all the logs.

I tried to understand all the logs and got the basic idea but just wanted to know a bit more about the logs as few terms are not understandable.

```
Apr  9 04:59:33 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: carrier acquired
Apr  9 04:59:33 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: adding address fe80::bac5:f37d:9bb4:65df
Apr  9 04:59:33 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: IAID eb:d3:4c:54
Apr  9 04:59:34 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Apr  9 04:59:34 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: offered 192.168.0.57 from 192.168.0.1
Apr  9 04:59:34 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Apr  9 04:59:34 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: probing address 192.168.0.57/24
Apr  9 04:59:35 device avahi-daemon[325]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::bac5:f37d:9bb4:65df.
Apr  9 04:59:35 device avahi-daemon[325]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr  9 04:59:35 device avahi-daemon[325]: Registering new address record for fe80::bac5:f37d:9bb4:65df on wlan0.       *.
Apr  9 04:59:38 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: leased 192.168.0.57 for 86400 seconds
Apr  9 04:59:38 device avahi-daemon[325]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.57.
Apr  9 04:59:38 device avahi-daemon[325]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Apr  9 04:59:39 device avahi-daemon[325]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.57 on wlan0.IPv4.
Apr  9 04:59:39 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: adding route to 192.168.0.0/24
Apr  9 04:59:39 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: adding default route via 192.168.0.1
Apr  9 04:59:39 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: removing route to 192.168.0.0/24
Apr  9 04:59:47 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: no IPv6 Routers available
Apr  9 05:15:49 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: carrier lost
Apr  9 05:15:49 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: deleting address fe80::bac5:f37d:9bb4:65df
Apr  9 05:15:49 device avahi-daemon[325]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::bac5:f37d:9bb4:65df on wlan0.
Apr  9 05:15:49 device avahi-daemon[325]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::bac5:f37d:9bb4:65df.
Apr  9 05:15:49 device avahi-daemon[325]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr  9 05:15:49 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: deleting default route via 192.168.0.1
Apr  9 05:15:49 device avahi-daemon[325]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.0.57 on wlan0.
Apr  9 05:15:49 device avahi-daemon[325]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.57.
Apr  9 05:15:49 device avahi-daemon[325]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
```

So above, it says carrier accquired and `192.168.0.57` was offered by the router(192.168.0.1). It tried to connect on that IP and leased was given for 86400 seconds (24hrs). But after this, when it says `wlan0: adding route to 192.168.0.0/24`. What does it means.?

I am not able to understand whats actully happening with it. Can anyone please explain this to me.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

“Carrier lost” could mean many things. Perhaps the router is set to only grant DHCP leases for 24 hours. In many cases, Network Manager will reconnect automatically but, in a few cases, fails.

It could indicate that the router is set to use auto channel selection and changed channels looking for a better connection. In quite a few cases, with Network Manager and native Linux drivers, NM doesn’t see the new channel immediately and simply drops. Here is some very interesting information about this: https://superuser.com/questions/1311149/why-do-wifi-routers-do-such-a-bad-job-of-channel-selection

For these reasons, I suggest that routers be set to WPA2-AES, sometimes known as CCMP and a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11.

Perhaps as bad is auto selection between the 2.4 gHz and 5 gHz segments of the router. I recommend that they be renamed separately, something like myrouter_2.4 and myrouter_5 or some such. As well, I recommend that the channel in the 5 gHz segment be fixed.

I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

After you have set your country code, see if your 5 gHz is subject to DFS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_allocation_schemes#DFS

```
sudo iw reg get
```

Here is a sample from my machine:

```
country US: DFS-FCC
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

As you can see, DFS (“We reserve the right to switch the channel at any time.”) is in effect for channels above 48 and below 149. Therefore, I recommend a channel outside that range. I use 149.

The exact reason that the carrier was lost is not available from the limited data in the log. All I can suggest is to try to eliminate every possible reason it may have occurred and see if the problem is resolved.